# How do you handle Membership/Roles when using NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm about to kick off a new project using NHibernate and ASP.Net MVC and have come upon the question of membership.  I'm wondering if I should use a 3rd party NHibernate Membership/Role provider, create my own, or just skip the providers all together.

So far I've looked at:
[Manuel Abadia's NHCustomProviders](http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,3b6ccb3f-2f2a-4dcb-a414-605371a00618.aspx) - It seems like a lot of configuraton, not sure if I want to put all that in my web.config.
[Leo Vildosola's NHibernateProvider](http://www.codeplex.com/nhibernateprovider) - Which doesn't appear to be supported by the project owner anymore since he doesn't use NHibernate anymore.
[Eucalypto](http://devage.com/Wiki/ViewArticle.aspx?name=eucalypto&version=0) - I like the table structure, but am a bit warry of all the extra CMS stuff it comes with.
* Each of these projects looks like it hasn't been touched in a while, which could mean extra work just getting them updated to use the newest version of NHibernate.

This is one of those problems that's been solved many times and I would like to spend my time solving new problems, and hopefully adding some business value.

Comment: Manuel's seems to be the most popular one.. Which one did u use finally?

Comment: Ended up rolling my own. Wasn't very difficult at all.
More recently, I've been using http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ and it's been great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled my own. It's actually a lot easier than most people think (I was surprised too) - once you actually get rolling, everything comes together pretty quickly. It's one thing to spend days or more solving a solved problem, but this took me all of a few hours including planning.

Comment: Would you be interested (or able) to share details of your implementation?

Comment: What aspect are you interested in? The c# code, the database schema ...?

Comment: The C# aspect, how you actually use it in Views, etc

Comment: Todd - the idea of a membership provider is that when you use it in your application, it's always the same no matter which provider you use. You can find out how to use any membership provider in your Views by reading up on membership providers in general.